# What sort of connectors are these?

Tags: connector, identification

I'm trying to find a three-pin connector like the ones photos below (taken from [this page](https://www.brewpi.com/fridge-hacking-guide/)). I have tried asking in the comments but my question is still 'awaiting moderation' after a week so I don't think they're checking them any longer. Can anybody here point me in the right direction?

[image: Picture of connectors in place]
[image: Close up]

Comment: I do not understand, do you have such connectors but can't get their name? If you need similar connectors, rephrase your question w/ something like: 'I need to carry such and such signal for this and that, and I'd like a connector that look like this, can you help?'. If you are not an expert, do not provide a solution, provide a problem.

Comment: round threaded connector - could be "M8"  probably off topic.

Comment: In the linked article the connector is called out as an M12.

Answer (score 5):

They explicitly name them as ***M12 panel mount connectors***. Three pin version.

Comment: Wow. Reading the article was the *only* necessary thing, really? Wow.

Answer (score 0):

M12 panel mount connector.
here is a link for that
https://www.amazon.in/Contacts-3-Pin-Aviation-Plug-Connector/dp/B07QGPJYSC